# Searching excel files for specific sheets to create a list

Tags: vba, excel

I have worked on this for a while.  It's my first Excel VBA macro and I think I am almost there.  I just can't seem to find a way to get the information I need from my function or I can't get my function to give me the right information.

I need a macro that will search through a selected folder and its sub-folders for excel workbooks that have specific sheet names contained with in then out put the paths to an excel spreadsheet.  Currently my code will either only find the files in a single folder or it will list all the files indiscriminately.  Now the code is a bit of a mess because i am unsure of which parts I need and which parts I don't.

```
            Option Explicit
    Public ObjFolder As Object
    Public objFso As Object
    Public objFldLoop As Object
    Public lngCounter As Long
    Public objFl As Object

    Sub ImportSheet()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim SourceFolder As String
        Dim FileList As Variant
        Dim GrabSheet As String
        Dim FileType As String
        Dim ActWorkBk As String
        Dim ImpWorkBk As String
        Dim NoImport As Boolean
        Dim FileToWriteTo As Variant
        Dim xRow As Long
        Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$
        Dim MyDir As String, myList()

        'Startup folder to begin filedialog search
        InitialFoldr$ = "C:"

         'Define filetype
        FileType = "*.xlsx"

        'Define sheetname to copy
        GrabSheet = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please enter name of sheet you wish to find.", Title:="Specify Sheet Name")


        'open dialog for user to select a folder to search

        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
            .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
            .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
            If .Show = True Then
                MyDir = .SelectedItems(1)
            End If
        End With
        On Error Resume Next
        myList = SearchFiles(MyDir, "*.xlsx", 0, myList())
        If Err = 0 Then

           'If user selects folder count the items to search
                xDirect$ = MyDir & "\"
                xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 8)

                'Creates list with filenames
                FileList = ListFiles(xDirect$ & FileType)

                'Imports data
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                ActWorkBk = ActiveWorkbook.Name
                NoImport = False

                'Clear contents of Active sheet and set active cell to A1
                Sheets(1).UsedRange.ClearContents
                Sheets(1).Select
                Range("A1").Select

                For i = 1 To UBound(FileList)

                    'Opens file
                    Workbooks.Open (xDirect$ & FileList(i))
                    ImpWorkBk = ActiveWorkbook.Name

                    'Checks to see if the specific sheet exists in the workbook
                    On Error Resume Next
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(GrabSheet).Select
                        If Err > 0 Then
                            NoImport = True
                            GoTo nxt
                        End If
                        Err.Clear
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$ & FileList(i))
                        Do While xFname$ <> ""
                        ThisWorkbook.Activate

                           ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = xDirect$ & xFname$
                            xRow = xRow + 1
                            xFname$ = Dir
                        Loop
                    'Copies sheet
                   'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(GrabSheet).Copy after:=Workbooks(ActWorkBk).Sheets(Workbooks(ActWorkBk).Sheets.Count)

                    'Renames the imported sheet
                    On Error Resume Next
                        ActiveSheet.Name = "Specs with " & GrabSheet
                        Err.Clear
                    On Error GoTo 0

    nxt:
                    'Closes importfile
                    Workbooks(ImpWorkBk).Activate
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
                    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                    'Workbooks(ActWorkBk).Activate

                Next i

                'Error if some sheets were not found
               ' If NoImport = True Then MsgBox "Some of the files did not contain the sheet " & GrabSheet

                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                 Else
                   MsgBox "No file found"
               End If
               On Error GoTo 0
    '         End If

        'End With

    'End Function
    End Sub

    'WITH SUBFOLDERS - Function that creates an array with all the files in the folder
    Private Function SearchFiles(MyDir As String, myFileName As String, n As Long, myList()) As Variant
        Dim fso As Object, myFolder As Object, myFile As Object
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        For Each myFile In fso.getfolder(MyDir).Files
            If (Not myFile.Name Like "~$*") * (myFile.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name) _
            * (myFile.Name Like myFileName) Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve myList(1 To 2, 1 To n)
                myList(1, n) = MyDir
                myList(2, n) = myFile.Name
            End If
        Next
        For Each myFolder In fso.getfolder(MyDir).subfolders
            SearchFiles = SearchFiles(myFolder.Path, myFileName, n, myList)
        Next
        SearchFiles = IIf(n > 0, myList, "")
    End Function

    'WITHOUT SUBFOLDERS - Function that creates an array with all the files in the folder
    Function ListFiles(Source As String) As Variant
        Dim GetFileNames() As Variant
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim FileName As String

        On Error GoTo ErrHndlr

        i = 0
        FileName = Dir(Source)
        If FileName = "" Then GoTo ErrHndlr

        'Loops until no more mathing files are found
        Do While FileName <> ""
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve GetFileNames(1 To i)
            GetFileNames(i) = FileName
            FileName = Dir()
        Loop
        ListFiles = GetFileNames
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Function

        'If error
      ErrHndlr:
        ListFiles = False
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Function
```

This will work right now to give a list using the "ListFiles" Function.
But I can't seem to figure out how to get it to out put a list using the "SearchFiles" Function.  Which, ultimately,is what I need it to do.

Please help i feel like I am so close!!!

Comment: The DIR() command can take wildcards to filter the results: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php

Comment: Finding the files works OK.  It is listing the file paths for each one found that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured it out.  I was having trouble with the syntax to access my array of arrays. here is the code that ended up doing the trick.

```
  Option Explicit
    Public ObjFolder As Object
    Public objFso As Object
    Public objFldLoop As Object
    Public lngCounter As Long
    Public objFl As Object


    Sub ImportSheet()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim GrabSheet As String
        Dim ActWorkBk As String
        Dim ImpWorkBk As String
        Dim NoImport As Boolean
        Dim xRow As Long
        Dim xFname As String
        Dim InitialFoldr As String
        Dim MyDir As String, myList()


        'Startup folder to begin filedialog search
        InitialFoldr = "C:\Users\george.EASYWAY\Desktop\TEST1\"

        'Define sheetname to copy
        GrabSheet = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please enter name of sheet you wish to find.", Default:="snagit", Title:="Specify Sheet Name")


        'open dialog for user to select a folder to search
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
            .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
            .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr
            If .Show = True Then
                MyDir = .SelectedItems(1)
            End If
        End With
        On Error Resume Next
        myList = SearchFiles(MyDir, "*.xlsx", 0, myList())
        If Err = 0 Then


         'Imports data
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         ActWorkBk = ActiveWorkbook.Name
         NoImport = False

         'Clear contents of Active sheet and set active cell to A1
         Sheets(1).UsedRange.ClearContents
         Sheets(1).Select
         Range("A1").Select

         For i = 1 To UBound(myList, 2)
             'Opens file
             Workbooks.Open (myList(1, (i)) & "\" & (myList(2, (i))))
             ImpWorkBk = ActiveWorkbook.Name

             'Checks to see if the specific sheet exists in the workbook
             On Error Resume Next
                 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(GrabSheet).Select
                 If Err > 0 Then
                     NoImport = True
                     GoTo nxt
                 End If
                 Err.Clear
             On Error GoTo 0

             xFname = Dir(myList(1, (i)) & "\" & (myList(2, (i))))
                 Do While xFname <> ""
                    ThisWorkbook.Activate
                    ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = (myList(1, (i)) & "\" & (myList(2, (i))))
                    xRow = xRow + 1
                    xFname = Dir
                 Loop


             'Renames the imported sheet
             On Error Resume Next
                 ActiveSheet.Name = "Specs with " & GrabSheet
                 Err.Clear
             On Error GoTo 0

        nxt:
             'Closes importfile
             Workbooks(ImpWorkBk).Activate
             Application.DisplayAlerts = False
             ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
             ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
             Application.DisplayAlerts = True
             'Workbooks(ActWorkBk).Activate

         Next i

         'Error if some sheets were not found
        ' If NoImport = True Then MsgBox "Some of the files did not contain the sheet " & GrabSheet

         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
          Else
            MsgBox "No file found"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Sub

    'Function that creates an array with all the files in the folder with subfolders
     Function SearchFiles(MyDir As String, myFileName As String, n As Long, myList()) As Variant
        Dim fso As Object, myFolder As Object, myFile As Object
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        For Each myFile In fso.getfolder(MyDir).Files
            If (Not myFile.Name Like "~$*") * (myFile.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name) _
            * (myFile.Name Like myFileName) Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve myList(1 To 2, 1 To n)
                myList(1, n) = MyDir
                myList(2, n) = myFile.Name
            End If
        Next
        For Each myFolder In fso.getfolder(MyDir).subfolders
            SearchFiles = SearchFiles(myFolder.Path, myFileName, n, myList)
        Next
        SearchFiles = IIf(n > 0, myList, "")

    End Function
```